# Is there any way for me to deploy a Telegram bot on a website?

Tags: javascript, python, nlp, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm building a bot on Telegram. I need to deploy this on a website. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

So simple , just use `<script> YOUR CODE </script>`. What's your problem?

Make requests to telegram, receive responds and handle them.
Check out my code at [GitHub](https://github.com/sepehrsamavati/Telegram-bot-template)

Comment: @SamarDikshit then you should use a server instead of host. Run .py on the server, make your own api or build the website on that server. Why you want to deploy it on a website? And what do you mean?